# Is it right to say "Try harder"

Tags: word-usage

I want say to somebody to try more in studying English. Is it right to say **Try harder**

Comment: Yes. What do you think the alternative is? Hopefully, not *try more hardly*?

Comment: May be "Try more".

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is definitely used quite commonly.

"Hardly" wouldn't be correct, as it has an entirely different meaning - you certainly don't want your English students to be 'hardly trying.' Ironically, this would mean exactly the opposite of what you're trying to express here.

'Harder' is the comparative form of 'hard,' which has the same form as an adverb that it does as an adjective. We push harder, we try harder, and we fight harder, in the same way that we run faster, drive faster, and move faster. We don't do anything 'fastly.'

These are just some notable exceptions to the '-ly' adverb rule.

So to answer, yes. It is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is grammatically correct.  **Hard** is an unusual adverb.  It has several meanings, but it is commonly used to mean **intensely**.  So **harder** means **more intensely**.   You might sound less casual if you said, "You should study English more intensely".